# How to print without repeated Header using this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I have a javascript function to print documents. The problem is the header is printed repeatedly after each page.

The JS function:

```
<script language="javascript">
var gAutoPrint = true;

function processPrint(){

if (document.getElementById != null){
var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
if (document.getElementsByTagName != null){
var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
if (headTags.length > 0) html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
}

html += '\n</HE' + 'AD>\n<BODY>\n';
var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("printMe");

if (printReadyElem != null) html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
else{
alert("Error, no contents.");
return;
}

html += '\n</BO' + 'DY>\n</HT' + 'ML>';

var printWin = window.open("","processPrint");
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();

if (gAutoPrint) printWin.print();
} else alert("Browser not supported.");

}   
</script>
```

The ID printMe is a `div` that contain a basic table. This `div` should be printed.

```
<div id='printMe'>
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</tr>
      <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</tr>
      <tr><td>xxx</td><td>xxx</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but this looks like a complex way to achieve what would normally be done with CSS @media directive(s).

Comment: I know. But, my whole team use this function.So, I can't use another method.

Comment: I can't see that it would make a difference but you could try giving `processPrint`a doctype.

Comment: Still the same. Repeated `<th>`

Comment: Could you post screenshots of what you expect and what you get?